# Firebase Firestore compound orderBy query not working

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

in my react app I'm reading my Firestore collections and used conditional query for filtering. and this queries contains multiple orderBy (price, date, type). each order has ascending and descending. and i used it like so.

```
const constraints = [];

    if (price)
      constraints.push(orderBy("price", price == "1" ? "desc" : "asc"));

    if (date)
      constraints.push(orderBy("postedDate", date == "1" ? "desc" : "asc"));

    const posts = collection(db, "allPosts");
    let q = query(livings, ...constraints);

    const qSnapshot = await getDocs(q);
```

when running this and filtering only by one of them, it works. but when i use the together it only works for the first query, in this case for price. no matter if i change the value before or after.

what is the solution for this? also does this happen with where query as well?

Answer (score 0):

Every query that you execute against Firestore needs a matching index. For single-field queries, the indexes are automatically generated. But for queries (including ordering results) involving multiple fields you will need to (often) explicitly define the composite index yourself.

If the index that is needed for a query is not found, the server sends back an error and the SDK raises that error. So you catch errors in your code and log them, you'll find the error message in your logging output. In that error message you'll find a **direct link** to the Firestore console to generate the exact index that is needed.

So:

1. Catch and log the error.
2. Find the message in the logging output.
3. Click the link in the error message.
4. Tell Firestore to generate the index with a single click.
5. Be patient while your existing data is indexed.
6. Try the query again. :)

Comment: i already indexed in firestore. but the order doesn't work for the second field if there is a first field

Comment: If you order on two fields, your second field will only impact results that have the same value for the first field.  If you want to display the documents in a different order, you will have to resort them in your application code.